# DRF (Django) hierarchy structure

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to create a hierarchy, and I added list of models, like that:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Form(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Type(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Form', related_name='form', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Point(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Point', related_name='point', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

So, please, advise how to handle this structure. I have to implement 2 cases:

1. I need to get a record from 'point' table and it should return it with all upper hierarchy: Point-Type-Form-Category
2. And I need to get all records from Category with full hierarchy(internal structure, which is under each record) too.

So, what is the best way or instruments to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, there are similar fields in each model(`name` and `parent`). Rather than designing like this, why don't you use the same model, for example like this:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = 'C'
    FORM = 'F'
    TYPE = 'T'
    POINT = 'P'
    CHOICES = (
        (CATEGORY, 'CATEGORY'),
        (FORM, 'FORM'),
        (TYPE, 'TYPE'),
        (POINT, 'POINT'),
    )
    node_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=CHOICES,
        default=CATEGORY
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, default=None, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
```

Now, if you want to get from point to type, then you can do like this:

```
def get_children(node):
   qset = Node.objects.filter(pk=node.pk)
   for child in node.children.all():
      qset.union(get_children(child)) # using recursion
   return qset

def get_parents(node):
  qset = Node.objects.filter(pk=node.pk)
  while(node.parent):
     qset.union(Node.objects.filter(pk=node.parent.pk))
     node = node.parent
  return qset
```

### Update

Lets say you have some extra data which might be relevent to the model for a point, you can make a OneToOne relation to that node and another model which will contain that extra data. For example:

```
class ExtraPoint(models.Model):
    point = models.OneToOneField(Node, related_name='point')
    data = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then you can access that data like this:

```
for node in Node.objects.all():
    if node.point:
        print(node.point.data)
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't think about approach like that, but how Django will detect which table should use to get data? I mean, I have 4 different tables and just one model for all of them, is it ok? And for what are we using 'node_type'? not sure, that fully understand

Comment: I didn't suggest to use different tables either. I suggested to use same table to store all data(category, point etc)

Comment: ou, I got your point... yeah, this is reasonable in this case. But what if we have another structure with more different fields in each model?

Comment: @MattBearson I have added an update section for that. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, really interesting approach, I didn't think about it at all before)